# Dynamic SQL Query With VB.net Variables String condition

Tags: sql, vb.net

Hi All probably a quick answer but I'm banging my head on this one thinking there must be a better way.

I have 4 strings if the condition of the string is not null or empty I add it to the query but the first will always not need the AND so I've added WHERE 1 = 1 then I can add an AND ID = @ID etc so all four can be added. What am I missing?

```
   Dim sqlBuilder As New StringBuilder()
    '1 = 1 allows an and.
    sqlBuilder.Append("SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1=1 ")

    If Surname <> "" Then
        sqlBuilder.Append(" AND Surname=@surname")
    End If
    If Payroll <> "" Then
        sqlBuilder.Append(" AND payroll = @payroll")
    End If
    If VehicleReg <> "" Then
        sqlBuilder.Append(" AND registration = @registration")
    End If
    If OrgID > 0 Then
        sqlBuilder.Append(" AND OrganisationID = @orgid")
    End If
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?  If so what is it?

Comment: What your doing seems fine to me, bout the only thing I would suggest is check the length of of your builder, then only add the "AND" if required

Comment: No error I was just wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: Personally I'd stick with this (or some other LINQ built chain) rather than one "god query".  See my comment on @jmcilhinney answer for why.

Answer (score 0):

There's an easy way to use a single, unchanging SQL query while making parameters optional, e.g.

```vb
Dim query = "SELECT * FROM Person WHERE (@FirstName IS NULL OR FirstName = @FirstName) AND (@LastName IS NULL OR LastName = @LastName)"
Dim command As New SqlCommand

command.CommandText = query

With command.Parameters
    .Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = If(firstNameTextBox.TextLength = 0, CObj(DBNull.Value), firstNameTextBox.Text)
    .Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = If(lastNameTextBox.TextLength = 0, CObj(DBNull.Value), lastNameTextBox.Text)
End With
```

By setting a parameter to NULL you effectively ignore it. For instance, if the `@FirstName` parameter is set to NULL then `@FirstName IS NULL` is true and that first set of criteria matches every row, otherwise it only matches those rows that contain the specified first name. Similarly for the second set of criteria. You can do the same thing for as many sets of criteria as you like, comparing the parameter to NULL or the column to the parameter.

One point to note is that I have used two parameters for four criteria in the example above. That is possible because `SqlClient` supports genuine named parameters. With providers that don't support genuine named parameters, e.g. Jet or ACE with `OleDb`, you actually need to add twice as many parameters because you can't use the same parameter twice in the SQL code, e.g.

```vb
Dim query = "SELECT * FROM Person WHERE (@FirstName1 IS NULL OR FirstName = @FirstName2) AND (@LastName1 IS NULL OR LastName = @LastName2)"
Dim command As New OleDbCommand

command.CommandText = query

Dim firstName = If(firstNameTextBox.TextLength = 0, CObj(DBNull.Value), firstNameTextBox.Text)
Dim lastName = If(lastNameTextBox.TextLength = 0, CObj(DBNull.Value), lastNameTextBox.Text)

With command.Parameters
    .Add("@FirstName1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = firstName
    .Add("@FirstName2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = firstName
    .Add("@LastName1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = lastName
    .Add("@LastName2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = lastName
End With
```

Comment: Only trouble with this is that there are different situations most likely have different optimal plans.  With this approach the optimiser will likely pick one plan based on the first parameters and stick with it.  By creating the SQL according to the parameters supplied as per the original, you get one plan per situation which is almost certainly going to be better.